# Cannot access macbook from another computer in local network

Tags: macos, tomcat, wireless-networking

I`m trying to access a webservice using tomcat running in a macbook pro from another computer inside my wifi network, but I cannot access.
Tomcat is running in 8080 port, the result for netstat -an | grep 8080 is:
tcp46      0      0  *.8080                 *.*                    LISTEN

and Mac OS firewall is disabled.

Comment: Do you have a firewall on the router?

Comment: No. In the others computers that is not mac, it works fine

Comment: You can try making the Tomcat instance listen on 0.0.0.0 instead of *.

Comment: don't you think that the problem is something with the mac computer? When I access the site from my inet ip (192.168.0.1:8080....) using the mac it works fine and tomcat can listen, but it doesn't works from another computer and mac being the server